# except not working with lookup error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-catch, lookup

I am currently running this line of code, and I keep getting a LookupError at line 2. Why am I getting that error even though I am trying to catch it?

```
try:
   raise LookupError()
except LookupError:
   print()
```

Comment: Could not reproduce the error. Code was running fine. Can you please add more of your code?

Comment: You need to add more of your code for anyone to understand the problem. This code is working fine so it is most likely another part of your code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it was just a problem with the vs code linter not running properly, thank you to anyone that helped.